# Validation set augmentations PyTorch example

Tags: image, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, data-augmentation

In [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html) PyTorch vision example for transfer learning, they are performing validation set augmentations, and I can't figure out why.

```
# Just normalization for validation
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}
```

As far as I know, data augmentations are to be made solely on the training set (and sometimes on the test set, in what is called Test Time Augmentations).

Why is it done here as well?
Also, why not just resizing straight to 224?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, *random* data augmentation is only allowed on the training set. You can apply data augmentation to the validation and test sets provided that none of the augmentations are random. You will see this clearly in the example you provided.

The training set uses many random augmentations (augmentations that use randomness usually have "random" in the name). However, the validation set only uses augmentations that don't introduce any randomness to the data.

One last important detail: when you use normalization on the validation and test set you *MUST* use the same exact factors you used for the training set. You will see that the example above kept the numbers the same.

The need to resize and then center crop comes from the fact the val set needs to come from the same domain of the train set, thus if the former was randomly resized and cropped to 224, the val set needs to deterministically resize and crop.

Comment: Thanks. And could you please add why not just resizing to 224? Also, is it necessary to have the same augmentations roughly?

Comment: If you use random augmentations in your training set, then it will be impossible to replicate that in the test sets. However, you should try to keep your test data as similar to the training data as possible.

Comment: Didn't understand, why is it important that the center of the images remain in the center of the augmented image? If you just resize to 224 why does it hurt? Resizing to 256 and then cropping to 224 means losing pixels in the sizes, while just resizing to 224 isnt

Comment: It could be important for lots of different reasons. One common reason is that the object in the image is in the center of the image. But it's impossible to tell without seeing the images.

Comment: @Jjang If your model was trained with images cropped to 224x224 from a 256x256 image then the reason you crop the test images as well is because this matches the data domain your model was trained with. Otherwise there will be a scaling difference between the domains. The reason you center crop (as opposed to random crop) is to have a deterministic test result (one that doesn't change each time you run test). Other common evaluation techniques include evaluating 5, 9, 10, or 18 crops on each test image and aggregating (in the 10/18 cases you also perform horizontal flipping on half the crops).